# How to dynamically create a listview using kendoui

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

How can i create a KendoUI ListView dynamically. I mean i want to create the div, dataSource,templates and add, edit and delete functionality dynamically. How can i do that using kendoui.

I have defined the template like

```
   <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
          <div class="products">           
      <ul><li>
    # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
        #= data[i] #
    # } #
    </li></ul>            

        <div class="edit-buttons">
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit</a>  

            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-delete-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span>Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>


   </script>
```

And then the dynamic template will be

```
    <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="edittemplate">
          <div class="product-view">

          <ul><li>
          # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
         <input type="text" data-bind="value:data[i]" name="ProductName" required="required" validationMessage="required" />
           # } #
           </li></ul>
         <div class="edit-buttons">
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-update-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Update</a>  

        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-cancel-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span>Cancel</a>
    </div>

    </div>

   </script>
```

And then i have done the scripting like

```
var data = ["Todd", "Steve", "Burke"];
 $("#dynamicdiv").kendoListView({
  template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
  editable:true,                                          
  dataSource:data,                                          
 editTemplate:kendo.template($("#edittemplate").html()),
 }).delegate(".k-edit-button", "click", function (e) {
       alert("dtjherut");
       listview.edit();
       e.preventDefault();
}).delegate(".k-delete-button", "click", function (e) {
       alert("clicking");
       var model = dataSource.view()[$(this).closest(".tm").index()];
       dataSource.remove(model);
       e.preventDefault();
       dataSource.sync();
 }).data("kendoListView");
```

Now the list view is loading with the three names and edit and delete buttons. But the delete and edit buttons are not working. I have not given the paths here for create, delete and update. Basically i need to create all the templates and datasources dynamically. 
Sorry if there are any mistakes.
Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am trying to define the template dynamically and add that template to the list view. But the list view is not displaying

Comment: Can you show the code that you have so far? You can edit this question or put a working example in JSFiddle or JSBin.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're doing it wrong way. In a constructor of kendo UI listview you have to pass a template for a single item, not the whole list, e.g.:

```
$("#listview").kendoListView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    template: "<div>#: data #</div>"
});
```

more details can be found here:
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/listview/overview#configuring-listview-behavior

Moreover, prior to that a dataSouce should be instantiated, e.g.:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({data: ["Todd", "Steve", "Burke"]});
```

Hope that helps to get started.